# How to use a scalar subquery in Db2's JSON_OBJECT's VALUE clause?

Tags: sql, json, db2

I'm trying to create a `JSON_OBJECT()` from a scalar subquery like this in Db2 LUW v11.5.4.0:

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'x' VALUE (SELECT 1 FROM sysibm.dual))
FROM sysibm.dual;
```

This produces

> An unexpected token ")" was found following "1 from sysibm.dual)".  Expected tokens may include:  "<interval_qualifier>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.26.14

A similar query works in Oracle, and I don't see, [from the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0070412.html), what I'm doing wrong in Db2. How can I construct a `JSON_OBJECT()` from a scalar subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These hacks, and possibly others, seem to work:

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'x' VALUE COALESCE(NULL, (SELECT 1 FROM sysibm.dual)))
FROM sysibm.dual;

SELECT
  JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'x' VALUE DECODE(1, 1, (SELECT 1 FROM sysibm.dual)))
FROM sysibm.dual;
```

Comment: So you just copy the content of the edit of Lukasz in a new answer and mark it as solution?

Comment: Dear @Anho, thank you so much for your very considerate comment. 1) it is not a copy of Lukasz answer, please review our answers very carefully. 2) I wrote my answer first, please look at timestamps very carefully. Lukasz was so kind as to augment my suggestions with other options. 3) Please don't assume evil before you are *very* sure.

Comment: You're right. Sorry. At time of posting, your comment was second and I wrongly assumed posts are ordered by creation time. I really should have checked further.

Comment: @Anho: No worries. Btw, it's a recommended practice on Stack Overflow to answer one's own questions in order to share knowledge. I already knew the answer when I posted the "question"...

Answer (score 1):

I would move the scalar subquery from `SELECT` list to `LATERAL` part which will be an exact equivalent. It should also satify the parser:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'x' VALUE my_scalar)
FROM sysibm.dual, LATERAL(SELECT 1 AS my_scalar FROM sysibm.dual);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=97d13454f0e081eadb2f4957322f2c99)**

---

**EDIT:**

Hack with function:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'x' VALUE MAX((SELECT 1 FROM sysibm.dual)))
FROM sysibm.dual;
```

Here `MAX` because it accepts a single argument and does not change data type(same as `COALESCE`/`DECODE`).

Comment: Interesting idea. In my case ([jOOQ support for `JSON_OBJECT`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/dev/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/json-functions/json-object-function/)), it won't be practical, because there are too many caveats when moving an expression from `SELECT` (or `ORDER BY`, `WHERE`, etc.) to the `FROM` clause. For example, the semantics of the asterisk `*` would change, also the alias of the lateral derived table and the synthetic column could produce conflicts. But it's great to see that this workaround, too, works - meaning that this is really just a parser bug.

Comment: @LukasEder Yes, then your approach with providing expression(function call) is a better one. I could propose `MAX`(not the aggregate one but rather `GREATEST` equivalent).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that function. Might be interesting to explore in general!

Comment: @LukasEder It seems `MAX/MIN` has its own quirks due to sharing the same name with agg function. [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=3e93831ca69038c904fd8b24f12adbbd). Staying with `COALESCE` seems to be the safest option.